# How to accurately estimate the gas cost of smart function F call inside F itself (ie: without using `estimateGas` rpc call offchain)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, evm

#### Use case:

I need to estimate the accurate gas cost of state-changing smart contract function `F`  on-chain.  I need to do this on-chain and inside `F` itself because I need to estimate the gas cost of calling function F (with different parameters) with very high throughtputs. ( up to hundreds of instances per seconds). If I could do gas estimate on-chain inside `F` itself, then I can have another contract batch calling multiple instances of F (with diff parameters) and give me gas estimates all in one 'eth_Call' rpc.

#### My current Approach:

```
function F()public returns(uint){
     uint gasLeftBefore = gasleft()

     ... contract logic

     uint gasLeftAfter = gasleft()
     return gasLeftAfter - before
}
```

#### Problem:

For my above approach, I expect my gas estimate on-chain to fully match that of `estimateGas` rpc call (maybe with some relatively constant offset. Taking into account the fact that some gas for messageCall and memory allocation has already been spent at the first line inside function F). The provider that executes the `eth_Call` to batch- estimate F's gas cost inside itself and the provider that serves `estimateGas` rpc are the same ( my local node running on GETH)

What I observe in practice is not the above. The difference between my on/off chain estimate could be anywhere between 15%-30% percent.

Note that my function F accepts only  primitive parameters (uint, address etc). Therefore, the memory allocation for calling function F with different parameters should be constant. This doesn't explain the non-constant difference between on-chain and off-chain gas estimate.

#### Question:

Can any solidity & evm expert point out what I am doing wrong with my on-chain estimate approach ? And What I need to do in order to reach my goal.

My goal is: having my on-chain gas estimate ( after applying some constant offset) be within 1%-2% of off-chain `estimateGas` rpc.

Comment: One possible problem with your approach is that gas refund are done when the transaction has finished.

Comment: Can you further clarify ?  As I understand it, all gas left at the end of transaction are refunded.  (ie: all gas left after 2nd `uint gasLeftAfter = gasleft()` call will be refunded ). How does that impact the accuracy of on-chain estimate ?

Comment: You are correct, unused gas is returned at the end of the transaction. I meant to say that gas to be refunded by reseting a storage slot (it used to be 5000 gas) isn't accounted by `gasleft`. Usually the storage related opcodes are the most expensive and they have a complicated formula depending on the use, and transaction type. Look for sstore here https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#a7-sstore.